# Accessing a nested hash in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following (snipped) parameters passed into my controller.

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"OK", "action"=>"set_incident_incident_status_id", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"incidents", "incident"=>{"incident_status_id"=>"1"}}
```

I know that if I want to select the incident, I can do:

```
@incident = Incident.find(params[:id])
```

How do I access the "incident"=>{"incident_status_id"=>"1"}?

I thought to try something like:

```
@incident_status = IncidentStatus.find(params[:incident => :incident_status_id])
```

But that didn't work.  I'm assuming it's just a syntax problem at this point, and I haven't found a solution yet.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small tweak:

```
@incident_status = IncidentStatus.find(params[:incident][:incident_status_id])
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting the following error: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for :incident:Symbol):